# Why this @import rule is not having any effect on this Web Component?

Tags: font-face, web-component, native-web-component

```js
const sheet = new CSSStyleSheet()
sheet.replace(`
  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap');
  p {
    color: red;
    font-family: 'Roboto';
  }
`)
customElements.define('my-component',
  class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super()
      const shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({
        mode: 'open'
      })
      shadowRoot.adoptedStyleSheets = [sheet]
      shadowRoot.innerHTML = '<p>my component</p>'
    }
  }
)
```

### Check here: https://jsfiddle.net/jdvivar/h1x2vs3u/

A custom tag `my-component` is created, a shadow root attached and an adopted stylesheet is copied inside. I think it should render the content with the correct font, but it does not. Only the color style is applied. Do you know why?

Comment: Because you are using FireFox, which doesn't support ``adoptedStyleSheets``? Your fiddle works fine in Chrome, Edge, Opera

Comment: I'm using Chrome 80 on macOS, none of my other browsers worked here either... but I tried on my Android's Chrome and it works! I guess it's about how novel the adopted stylesheets tech is at this point, thanks to point it out to me.

Comment: https://github.com/WICG/construct-stylesheets/issues